# Excel IFS formula - range of number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, formula

I have a value in cell `AB8` and I want to conditionally return a status depending on which value it takes between 1 and 30.

I want to save time and rather than type the scores 1-9 indivdually to turn into "EMERGING" (etc) is there a way I can put a range in?

```
IFS(AB8=1,"EMERGING",AB8=2,"EMERGING",AB8=3,"EMERGING",AB8=4,"EMERGING",AB8=5,"EMERGING",AB8=6,"EMERGING",AB8=7,"EMERGING",AB8=8,"EMERGING",AB8=9,"DEVELOPING",AB8=10,"DEVELOPING",AB8=11,"DEVELOPING",AB8=12,"DEVELOPING",AB8=13,"DEVELOPING",AB8=14,"DEVELOPING",AB8=15,"DEVELOPING",AB8=16,"DEVELOPING",AB8=17,"SECURING",AB8=18,"SECURING",AB8=19,"SECURING",AB8=20,"SECURING",AB8=21,"SECURING",AB8=22,"SECURING",AB8=23,"SECURING",AB8=24,"SECURING",AB8=25,"READY",AB8=26,"READY",AB8=27,"READY",AB8=28,"READY",AB8=29,"READY",AB8=30,"READY")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=INDEX({"EMERGING","DEVELOPING","SECURING","READY"},MATCH(AB8,{0,9,17,25},1))
```

---

Or create this table in, say, `A1:B4`:

```
0   Emerging
9   Developing
17  Securing
25  Ready
```

And then the formula is just:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(AB8,$A$1:$A$4,1))
```

Comment: This works for a value more than 30 too. I guess 30 is the end limit

Comment: @GowthamShiva It wouldn't be difficult to wrap a `IF(AB8<=30,INDEX(...))` around this. OP has clearly shown they are familiar with `IF` statements so I left it in the cleanest form. Who knows, OP might never encounter values greater than 30 anyway.

Comment: The last '1' in the match part is amazing. Is that returning the nearest match?

Comment: @GowthamShiva, it returns a the closest match that is *less than or equal to* the lookup_value

Comment: @GowthamShiva, I'm pleased you like my answer -- you know the way to show that is by *upvoting*?

Answer (score 0):

CallumDA's answer is more clean.

But this can be accomplished with nested IF formulas.

```
=IF(AB8>=1,IF(AB8<=8,"EMERGING",IF(AB8<=16,"DEVELOPING",IF(AB8<=24,"SECURING",IF(AB8<=30,"READY")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one might also work,

```
=IF(AND(AB8>=1,AB8<=8),"EMERGING",IF(AND(AB8>=9,AB8<=16),"DEVELOPING",IF(AND(AB8>=17,AB8<=24),"SECURING",IF(AB8<=30,"READY","INVALID NUMBER"))))
```